# Encode Decoding and bytearray casting error

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to understand why `2` and `5` commands raise errors:

```
1 >>> s = 'itï¿½s'

2 >>> s.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

3 >>> print s.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
itï¿½s

4 >>> bytearray(s.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8'))
bytearray(b'it\xc3\xaf\xc2\xbf\xc2\xbds')

5 >>> bytearray(s.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8', 'ignore'), 'utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I assumed `s.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode('utf-8')` was converting `s` to `utf-8` and ignoring weird things. So, why casting to `bytearray` encoding in `utf-8` raises an error?

Comment: 2: Implicit decoding; `s` is **already encoded**, so trying to encoding it again triggers a decoding from ASCII first.

Comment: Same for 5; you passed in a bytestring, *and* a codec, so the bytestring is decoded first.